# Create hierarchical relations between a set of terms

Tags: taxonomy, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling, lsa

I need to form hierarchical relations between a set of terms(which may be entities, nouns,etc) by mining the web. This is along the lines of a taxonomy, However I need to be able to link Proper Nouns(people) and entities in a meaningful manner.

Eg :

```
{Movies,Avengers: Age of Ultron,Robert Downey Junior}
```

Should be linked as

```
Movies -> Avengers: Age of Ultron -> Robert Downey Junior
```

How should I go about doing this?